# Wireguard Handshake Success on Centos as Server but nothing loads on clients

Tags: networking, vpn, centos, openvpn, wireguard

Below as you can see my client does indeed connect to my server as it shows a handshake. But when connected, my client can't access any url's in the browser. What else can I me missing in my setup?

I have my wg0-server.conf file also posted below.

Do I need to add an endpoint under the [ peer ] setting in my server.conf file? Because in the peer output it shows that its connected on port 43279, but it should be 10103.

Server output on wg command:

[image: Server output on wg]

---

**My server wg0-server.conf file:**

[image]

---

**My client conf file:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding in the iptables line seems to have fixed it to my server.conf file:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

[image]

Or just skip all that configuring and just download and run this script:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-n-s/wireguard-install/master/wireguard-install.sh -O wireguard-install.sh
```

Comment: Also this quick wireguard tutorial helps: https://github.com/l-n-s/wireguard-install -- simple bash script to install wireguard in less than a minute.

Comment: Also after connecting, I had some speed issues as it it wasn't up to par compared to my openvpn setup. I set the MTU to 1360 on the client side. Overall the wireguard install was simple after the fact. Basic idea is that you need to generate a public key pair on the server + client. Then share it among both to get it to work with mainly the commands **wg** and **wg-quick up wg0-server**.